# ssh public key authentication failed

Tags: ssh, aix

I have set up an SSH connection between two AIX servers. But it fails when I try to `ssh` to the server side, sending public key packets and receiving no reply.

Both client and server users are passwordless, however it should not matter for I user public key authentication.

The client public key is:

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAr01elV9Q+bMahM3PTrzW7ojF//5kaXr3unKj7IoD/bJFAR5Eo65oo85yJtedOW2MHuvzhTdc+volo1JIB4B+1vK2vixxehXyF+6KOFOg523Gp6JXlsFl3G94anFRbI9mdhyZl6TAdg02237apCq4L55cjWOLgzqYOhI4mH1Nh+dYrvogIQnmHxRMVAl73DSHCKEudOsOhk1aMZuLQD14RUW0J85Jd3baMjucYV7ruvTbLQnl0/tECzcjh7U0JcCWqKJJiZCd4z9ezMXMQ2Qtwy/1LNTt6ePYabmnfH/9esG/xXrwAfAHUVn4+HrcnuFEuyKxXtPicctXoMlEwaCZ3Q== oracle@hostname
```

The permissions for the files in `~/.ssh` are:

```
-rw-r--r--    1 tuxedo   tuxedo          657 Apr 01 2012  known_hosts.20120401
-rw-r--r--    id_rsa.pub
-rw-------    id_rsa
-rw-r--r--    known_hosts
-rw-r--r--    authorized_keys
drwxr-xr-x      .ssh
-rw-------     id_dsa
```

Below is the debugging log obtained with `ssh -vvv user@hostname`:

```
OpenSSH_5.8p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Failed dlopen: /usr/krb5/lib/libkrb5.a(libkrb5.a.so):   0509-022 Cannot load module /usr/krb5/lib/libkrb5.a(libkrb5.a.so).
    0509-026 System error: A file or directory in the path name does not exist.
debug1: Error loading Kerberos, disabling Kerberos auth.
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to FTAS_DB_FZ [192.169.12.35] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/home/oracle/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug1: identity file /home/oracle/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/oracle/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/home/oracle/.ssh/id_dsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug1: identity file /home/oracle/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/oracle/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.8
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.8 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.8
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "ftas_db_fz" from file "/dev/null"
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 0 keys
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 135/256
debug2: bits set: 500/1024
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA e4:0a:0f:4f:8f:4e:02:cb:f3:6a:5b:50:54:6a:1d:f9
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "ftas_db_fz" from file "/dev/null"
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 0 keys
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "192.169.12.35" from file "/dev/null"
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 0 keys
Warning: Permanently added 'ftas_db_fz,192.169.12.35' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
debug2: bits set: 515/1024
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/oracle/.ssh/id_rsa (2004b488)
debug2: key: /home/oracle/.ssh/id_dsa (0)
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/oracle/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: /home/oracle/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA 36:5a:53:73:38:13:c1:1a:b5:bd:94:64:b5:f0:fa:c9
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup keyboard-interactive
debug3: remaining preferred: password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug2: userauth_kbdint
debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: userauth_kbdint: disable: no info_req_seen
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: 
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
debug3: packet_send2: adding 64 (len 51 padlen 13 extra_pad 64)
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
Permission denied, please try again.
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
debug3: packet_send2: adding 64 (len 51 padlen 13 extra_pad 64)
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
Permission denied, please try again.
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
debug3: packet_send2: adding 64 (len 51 padlen 13 extra_pad 64)
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
Received disconnect from 192.168.12.22: 2: Too many authentication failures for oracle
```

Comment: chmod go= ~/.ssh ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

Comment: The server you are connecting to - in the user's home directory, are the permissions of `.ssh` and `authorized_keys` correct, does `authorized_keys` have the correct content and finally, does your `sshd_config` on the target server allow `authorized_keys` and is that the right filename (it can be changed in the `sshd_config`)

Comment: Your system is ready for a little upgrade: OpenSSH 5.8 should be replaced with OpenSSH 8.3 (Its dependencies have to be upgraded too (OpenSSL for example))

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your private key seems to have been generated either in a different OS or SSH implementation which the SSH client does not understand. These lines are telling (more are included in the debug you gave):

```
debug3: Could not load "/home/oracle/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
```

Did you import it from a Linux or Windows machine? Perhaps you can try (re)generating a private key in the AIX client and upload that in the AIX server?

Answer (score 0):

All the keys and files in .ssh directory should have permission only for the user, not for group or other. Correct this and try again

Comment: I have change the keys and files in .ssh directory to 600, but it seems no effect.

Comment: Do you have your public key added to authorized_keys on server?